# Block all routes for scope from controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am trying to access a condition where user Logs in and If his account is deactivated he/she should be redirected back to the login page with a flash message I am trying something like this

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
 if resource.group.slug == 'a'
   @u = User.find_by_email(resource.email)
   if @u.member.state_id == "someid"
     '/logout'
     flash[:notice]= "My message."
   else
     a_root_path
   end
 elsif resource.group.slug == 'b'
   b_root_path
 elsif resource.group.slug == 'c'
   c_root_path
 else
   new_user_session_path
 end
```

`end`

Any suggestions how can I stop a user from log in and block all other routes for that scope ?

Answer (score 0):

the return value for after_sign_in_path_for method should be the url you want to redirect to. Thus you do not need to call redirect_to by yourself.

```
if @u.member.state_id == "someid"
  flash[:notice]= "My message."
  '/logout'
else
  a_root_path
end
```

(not tested)

Comment: But if I call the logout method(devise generated) it should log's the user out right?? It should not allow the user to logs in.But in my case it is allowing.

Comment: You mentioned "... and If his account is deactivated he/she should be **redirected back to the login page** with a flash message", then do you mean you want to let the user logged in, but still show the login page to the user?

Comment: Hey Thanks Peter I have updated my question, I don't want the user to log in if the condition is false that is account is deactivated.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you signout the user. as follows

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
 if resource.group.slug == 'a'
  @u = User.find_by_email(resource.email)
  if @u.member.state_id == "someid"
    sign_out resource
    '/users/sign_in' (or root_path based on your requirement)
    flash[:notice]= "My message."
  else
    a_root_path
  end
 elsif resource.group.slug == 'b'
  b_root_path
 elsif resource.group.slug == 'c'
  c_root_path
 else
  new_user_session_path
 end
```

Comment: Thanks AK.....@u.sign_out I cant use as it is giving me an  error undefined method sign_out. /logout works fine but it doesn't block login through other url's.

Comment: For that particular user like from dashboard link if he tries he get's login.

Comment: It's givin me undefined method `user_url' for #<Auth::SessionsController:0xd34b2ac>

Comment: Still my main motive is, if the user won't be able to login anyhow from any path for example if he tries to login from a url says "abc.com/dashboard" instead of "abc.com/login".He should not be allowed to login

Comment: Better way to solve your problem will be to write one more before filter method which will check if user account is active and then redirect the user to his account page otherwise will signout the user.

Comment: That was the last thing I was thinking about...So I can't restrict the user from the devise controller. I was using something reset_session in my action.